# How do I properly use keys with React functional components? Here's my like button:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, components, state

I'm trying build a Facebook-esque like button with React to get a better handle on stateful components. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I think it's the keys.

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {numLikes, onSelect}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at LikeButton.js:8)
    in LikeButton (at App.js:10)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

Here's App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import LikeButton from './components/LikeButton';

function App() {
  const [likes, updateLikes] = useState(23);
  const [liked, updateLiked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <LikeButton 
    secret='like-button'
    numLikes={likes}
    // status={liked}
    onSelect={(liked) => {
      if (liked) {
        updateLikes(likes + 1);
       } else { updateLikes(likes - 1)
       };
      updateLiked(!liked);
      }
    }
    />
    // onClick function here, or in LikeButton.js?
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's LikeButton.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import FaThumbsUp from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function LikeButton(secret, numLikes, onSelect) {
    return (
      <>
        <div key={secret} onClick={onSelect}>Like Button</div>
        <p>{numLikes}</p>
      </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Comment out the `<p>{numLikes}</p>` from your LikeButton.js and then if that fixes it, console log the `numLikes` because it might not be an integer like you think it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using properties in functional component you need to destruct the props, not take them individually. Because properties of a component are the first parameter in the function

```
import React from 'react';
import FaThumbsUp from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function LikeButton({secret, numLikes, onSelect}) {
    return (
      <>
        <div key={secret} onClick={() => onSelect(true)}>Like Button</div>
        <div key={secret} onClick={() => onSelect(false)}>Dislike Button</div>
        <p>{numLikes}</p>
      </>
    );
}
```

When you get a error of this type, know that you are trying to render a property or variable that is not a React element or non-object type data.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers!

Comment: Problem now is, `likes` only increments. It seems that `liked` is not alternating between `true` and `false`.

Comment: I will modify my answer to address that issue. You dont have dislike button and also your `onSelect` does not send data at all.

Comment: I'm trying to have the like button decrement when it's clicked, and the state variable `liked` is `true`. The opposite should also be true, so that the button works just like on facebook. I thought the `updateLiked` function would alternate the value of `liked`, and it should, but for some reason that code block isn't firing. My editor says `liked` is declared but never used. I think the problem is that my parameter `liked` isn't really my state variable `liked`.

Comment: You dont need to have `liked` flag at all. Just set the counter based on wheat LikeButton does. If your like button does only increment, just to the increment. you dont need `liked` state at all

Answer (score 1):

secret, numLikes, onSelect are inside of props object. you should destruct before use.

`const {secret, numLikes, onSelect} = props`